# Duplicates using distinct operator

Tags: sql-server-2012, distinct-values

I have below tables.

```
create table html_details(A int,b int,c int,d nvarchar(4))

create table pdf_details(A int,b int,c int,d nvarchar(4))

insert into pdf_details values(1,2,3,'pdf')
insert into pdf_details values(1,2,3,'pdf')
insert into pdf_details values(4,5,6,'pdf')

insert into html_details values(1,2,3,'html')
insert into html_details values(1,2,3,'html')
insert into html_details values(4,5,6,'html')
```

now i am using below query to avoid duplication in each tables.

```
select distinct a,b,c,d from html_details
union all
select distinct a,b,c,d from pdf_details
```

but above query gives poor performance because of distinct function in both query.so i am using distinct in outer query.Now performance is improved, but will it give same output?Both query are same in logic?

```
select distinct a,b,c,d from (
select  a,b,c,d from html_details
union all
select a,b,c,d from pdf_details
)a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will not return the same output.

Distinct in individual queries will get you unique records from both the queries and then it will be union-ed. So if there are similar rows in both the queries results, both of them will be present in final result.

Lets say your data is:

Table 1:

`1,2,3,pdf
1,2,3,pdf
1,2,3,hello`

Table 2:

`1,2,3,html
1,2,3,html
1,2,3,hello`

First approach's result will be (There's no distinct in final response) -

`1,2,3,pdf
1,2,3,hello
1,2,3,html
1,2,3,hello`

Second approach's result will be (There's a distinct in final response) -

`1,2,3,pdf
1,2,3,html
1,2,3,hello`

I hope this explains.